# How to swap groups position using RowGroup in PrimeNG?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm trying to swap groups but not having any luck. Basically I have to group them in this order:

```
ROOM3
 - Yoga, Martha   busy-3
 - Bacon, Anna    busy-3
   .........
   ...............
ROOM1
 - Brady, Marsha     busy
 - McDonald, Jane    busy
 ...............
 ....................
ROOM2 
 - Steve, Ana      busy-2
 - tester          busy-2
 .........
 ...............
```

In simple words I want to keep the order of the grouping like this:

> ROOM3 --> ROOM1 --> ROOM2

**Here's my working code:**

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1QnAlysncdPdqMgeunsj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better solution but if you add a `roomOrderId` to each row of your `data` object, then you can sort by this field :

```
sortField="roomOrderId"
```

**Edit**
You can manually add `roomOrderId` to each row :

```
    this.data.forEach(function(row) {
      if(row.room==="ROOM1") {
        row.roomOrderId = 2;
      } else if(row.room==="ROOM2") {
        row.roomOrderId = 3;
      } else if(row.room==="ROOM3") {
        row.roomOrderId = 1;
      }
    });
```

See my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y03s77SXCZ1pGMMCOVgt?p=preview)

Comment: this solution will solve it. However, the data that I will be getting back is not a simple array like my example and I won't be able to hard code or add extra fields like you are doing in your solution. Do you have another solution? Thank you!

Comment: You can manually add roomOrderId to each row. See my edited Plunker.

Comment: @Antiknippe. Thanks a lot bro!!

Answer (score 0):

i added extra pos field in data object:

```
data = [
    { box: '',  name: 'Brady, Marsha', status: 'busy', room: 'ROOM1' ,pos:2},
    { box: '1', name: 'Davis, Kevin', status: 'busy-1' , room: 'ROOM1',pos:2},
    { box: '1', name: 'Carter, Dawn',  status: 'busy-1' , room: 'ROOM1',pos:2},
    { box: '',  name: 'McDonald, Jane',status: 'busy', room: 'ROOM1',pos:2 },
    { box: 'MA',name: 'Bacon, Anna', status: 'wbusy-3', room: 'ROOM3',pos:1 },
    { box: 'MA',name: 'Yoga, Martha', status: 'busy-3', room: 'ROOM3' ,pos:1},
    { box: '1', name: 'Steve, Ana', status: 'busy-2', room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '2', name: 'tester', status: '', room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '3', name: 'Jhonson, Francisco', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '4', name: 'Mathews, Susan', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '5', name: 'Davis, Christine', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '6', name: 'Wheaters, Bob', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '7', name: 'Kinsky, Annabelle' , status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '8', name: '', status: '', room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '9', name: 'Stephanapolous', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: '10',name: 'Kelley, Tom', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3},
    { box: 'T', name: 'Peterson, James', status: 'busy-2' , room: 'ROOM2',pos:3}
]
```

and in html :

```
<p-dataTable [value]="data" sortField="room" rowGroupMode="subheader" groupField="room" expandableRowGroups="true"
        [sortableRowGroup]="false" sortField="pos" sortOrder="1">
    <ng-template pTemplate="rowgroupheader" let-rowData>{{rowData.room}} - INFO</ng-template>
    <p-column field="status" header="ID"></p-column>
    <p-column field="name" header="Title"></p-column>

</p-dataTable>
```

which will sort in your given order.

Comment: this solution will solve it. However, the data that I will be getting back is not a simple array like my example and I won't be able to hard code or add extra fields like you are doing in your solution. Do you have another solution? Thank you!